# jQuery slideToggle menus that collapses sibling menus before opening/closing itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

Here's a crude sample of what I'm dealing with: http://jsfiddle.net/dX2ux/1/

A client's in-house developed CMS dynamically creates menus using this HTML structure. It also comes with the jQuery script that is shown on the sample.

I want to edit the script so that it closes it's sibling's open menus before it toggles itself open. The `show` class is has to be toggled as well.

So far, I've come up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/dX2ux/2/

But if you play with it, it screws up when you click one of the sub menus.

Can anyone shed some light on how I might achieve the behavior I'm aiming for? Also, is this the best way to do it? Am I overthinking this?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really sure if this is the "best" way per se, but with that kind of markup, this solution should work:

```
$('.toggle-menu').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().siblings().children('.toggle-menu').removeClass('show').next().slideUp();
    $(this).toggleClass('show').next().slideToggle();
});
```

Edited your fiddle to show the effect: http://jsfiddle.net/dX2ux/3/